# Add Jira issue number to git commit message automatically in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, jira

We add *Jira Issue #* to the commit message to link the change with the *Jira Issue*. As the issue number is added manually, it is prone to human error. As we always have this number in the Git branch_, can the commit message have default value of this branch name? Can it be done with an *vs code* extension or *git templates*?

[image: Issue key example in VS Code]

Answer (score 6):

I created this file called `prepare-commit-msg` that I copied inside the `.git/hooks` folder

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Get the current branch name
current_branch=`git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`

# Search Jira ID in a pattern such a "feature/ABCD-123-my-feature"
id=$(echo $current_branch | sed -nE 's,[a-z]+/([A-Z]+-[0-9]+)-.+,\1,p')

# Only prepend if an ID was found in the current branch
if [[ ! -z $id ]]; then
 # $1 is the name of the file containing the commit message
 # Prepend "ABCD-123: "
 sed -i.bak -E "1s/^/${id}: /" $1
fi
```

Here's the gist: https://gist.github.com/raduchiriac/36b6269bebb75cfac7371acb1459fdcc

NOTE: you will find many solutions that use `sed -nr`, unfortunately that doesn't work post-Sierra anymore. Use `-E`

Comment: This actually worked!
I have found similar tutorial : https://medium.com/bytelimes/automate-issue-numbers-in-git-commit-messages-2790ae6fe071

Answer (score 1):

Actually I've found `Flow / Jira Commit Prefix` extension that does pretty much what I need. One can adjust the sources by it's need.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you using a `commit-msg` local hook and `pre-receive` server hook for your purpose. *Git hooks* are scripts that validate and modify repository writing operations - you may get acquainted with them in the official documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Local `commit-msg` hook may extract the ticket name from the branch and append it to the message, if none has already been found there. It can even cancel the commit process, if the branch name does not satisfy naming requirements.

The prime disadvantage of this approach is that any developer **should put the local hook manually** due to security considerations, so one may also forget or ignore this. Therefore, you also need a server-side `pre-receive` hook to decline pushed branches whether one of new commits contains an invalid message.

Comment: It's not exactly what I want. I tried to create prepare-commit-msg hook, but it doesn't update vscode editor

Comment: @DmitrijKultasev I stil cannot get VSCode to run the prepare-commit-msg script. Did you manage to fix in the meantime? any news?

Answer (score 0):

[Git Prefix](https://github.com/srmeyers/git-prefix) does the job.

Example Flow Jira Commit Prefix setting: ([A-Z]{3,6}-[0-9]{2,6})(.*)

[image]